# Access a class's method

Tags: error, magento-1.8, class

I am trying to access a class's method using `Mage::getSingleton()`

I have done the following:

```
<?php $allReviews = Mage::getSingleton('efkreports/product_allReviews')->getAllProductReviews(); ?>
<?php zend_debug::dump($allReviews); ?>
```

But this is giving me error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllProductReviews() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\efk\app\design\frontend\default\efk1\template\catalog\product\list\related.phtml on line 37

I even tried using:

```
<?php $allReviews = $this->Mage::getSingleton('efkreports/product_allReviews')->getAllProductReviews(); ?>
```

which is giving me same error..

Please help me in how to call a method through a class name..

**EDIT**:

#### Config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Reports>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Efk_Reports>
    </modules>
    <global>        
        <blocks>
            <efkreports>
                <class>Efk_Reports_Block</class>
            </efkreports>
        </blocks>
    </global>    
</config>
```

#### Class

```
//This class is for getting Best selling products list
class Efk_Reports_Block_Product_AllReviews extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract
{
   public function getAllProductReviews(){
        //some calculations here

        return $_productCollection;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the class exists? Can you post the config.xml of the module and the `allReviews` class (at least its path on the disk)

Comment: @Marius updated..

Comment: @Marius Does what I am doing here should work in normal cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage::getSingleton` creates an instance of a model and returns it as a singleton. You are trying to work with a block. For this try:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('efkreports/product_allReviews')
```

or

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('efkreports/product_allReviews')
```